# Output csv file to specific path in S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have written a Lambda function that terminates in the creation of a csv file.
I'd like to be able to store that csv file output to a particular path of my S3 bucket.
I understand that S3 has no file system in the traditional sense, but the path is as follows:

```
bucket-name/folder/file.csv
```

I can get the file to be saved in the location `bucket-name/`, but that's it.

Code for repro

```
import pandas as pd  
import io 
from io import BytesIO
from io import StringIO
import boto3 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    the_data = {'col1':['the','quick','brown','fox','jumped','over','the','lazy','dog'],
             'col2': 
['foo','bar','barfoo','oofarb','brafoo','barofo','forabo','broofa','borafa']}
    
    the_df = pd.DataFrame(the_data)
    
    
    bucket = 'bucket-name' 
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    the_df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'file.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Additionally, s there a better way to do this that doesn't require StringIO at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `StringIO` buffer.

If it's first argument is `None` (the default), `df.to_csv()` will return the CSV formatted data as a string.

```
the_data = {'col1': ['the','quick','brown','fox','jumps','over','a','lazy','dog'],
            'col2': ['foo','bar','barfoo','oofarb','brafoo','barofo','forabo','broofa','borafa']}

the_df = pd.DataFrame(the_data)

bucket = 'bucket-name' 
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'folder/file.csv').put(Body=the_df.to_csv())
```

Answer (score 0):

We can append folder path to file name as `folder/file.csv` and pass it to key

```
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'file.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

to

```
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'folder/file.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer although I have yet to validate.

Answer (score 0):

The path can be treated as the object's key. Depending on your constraints, you might be able to avoid dependence on both StringIO and Pandas. Re-organized input data could also simplify things.

```
the_data = {'col1':['the','quick','brown','fox','jumped','over','the','lazy','dog'],
             'col2': ['foo','bar','barfoo','oofarb','brafoo','barofo','forabo','broofa','borafa']}

keys = tuple(the_data)
rows = [keys] + list(zip(*[the_data[k] for k in keys]))
body = "\n".join([",".join(x) for x in rows])

s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'folder/file.csv').put(Body=body)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer although I have yet to validate.